# How to send object using FormData() by jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery

Check the code bellow. I want to send object from jquery ajax to mvc5 controller. I already tried like bellow but on controller object is not accessible. Can anyone tell me how to access this object from controller? Note: I have to use jquery `FormData()` because its having others image file and this object. So i cant use any other method.

C# mvc5 Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Update()
        {
            var fff = Request.Form["data"];
return Json("ok");
        }
```

Jquery:

```
var formData = new FormData();
            var obj = {
                Username: "user5",
                Email: "em@example.com"
            };

            formData.set("data", obj);
            console.log(obj);

            //Ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: "/TestController/Update",
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: formData, //Send form Data
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

[Picture of debug on mvc5 controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeJbh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to get object details from FormData() to Controller

VB.Net

```
 Dim objUser As cls_User = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of cls_User )(Request("data"))
```

C#

```
cls_User objUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cls_User>(Request("data"));
```

You need to create a class to capture the data coming from `FormData()` and then use the same object to retrieve it from `(Request("data")` to  `Dim objUser As cls_User`